# Adding a column to a DataSet (xsd) for a Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, dataset

I am working on a report and need to add a column to one of my datasets and to the RPT file, but when I try to modify the Data Set, I get an error that the specified table doesn't exist.  When I look in the code, it looks like there was originally a table used for this purpose, but this approach has been abandoned, and now this is instead being done with a DataSet in code that is attached to the report.

My problem is that I need to add this new column in the report and I can't seem to get a handle on the data in a way so I can drag my new field onto the report, because I can't find the needed piece of the DataSet because it doesn't exist as it previously did, and the in code DataSet now takes it's place.

Anyone out there able to point me in the right direction for how to go about making this work?

**UPDATE:**
This is roughly how my data set gets to the Crystal Report

```
private Sub ShowReport()
    Dim dsStatsForPlanned As DataSet = Nothing
    dsStatsForPlanned = DirectCast(Session(CreateSessionKey()), DataSet)
    plannedProductRpt.SetDataSource(dsStatsForPlanned)
End Sub
```

I have added the additional field that I need in the DataSet that comes in from Session, but am trying to use Designer to get this extra field onto the report, and when I try to refrech or change the Data Source, Designer tells me that the table doesn't exist, presumably because this table exists only in memory, and doesn't tie directly back to a SQL table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several days of digging, and finding a lot of information that was not helpful, I finally managed to find the answer to my issue in a post from 2006 here:

http://sstjean.blogspot.com/2006/12/xsdexe-and-msdatasetgenerator-operate.html

What I did to fix my problem:

- Manually edit the XSD file in a text editor and add the columns that I needed.  This made them appear in my XSD when viewed within Visual Studio.
- Run the specified Custom Tool for the XSD to regenerate the DataSet.  In my case it was the MSDataSetGenerator.  This was listed on the Properties tab in VS, and I could right click on the XSD in Solution Explorer and select Run Custom Tool.
- Open my RPT file and run Verify Databse.  This **finally** indicated that the database had changed and it was updating the report, and I now saw my new field in the Report Designer.

Comment: I can't find MSDataSetGenerator. When I right click on the .xsd in solution explorer, there only `open with ...`

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to actually modify the data outside of Crystal. So whether that means changing your query, or updating the .xsd, you'd add your column there. Then in Crystal Reports, you would go to "Database" in the menu bar, and choose "Verify Database" if your datasource/location hasn't changed, or "Set datasource location" if it has. Once you reverify the datasource, your new column should appear in the database fields, and you'll be able to drag it into your report.

Comment: This approach has worked perfectly in the past with other data sets, but it does not appear to work for how this current data set is brought to this report. I updated the original question with an explanation of how my data set is being bound to the report.

Comment: Are you the original author of the report? If so, how did you initially create the DataSource? What about creating a new data source to replace Session? I know that's not ideal, but maybe something like Session2 might work to make Designer recognize the changes.

Comment: That's part of the problem, I'm not the original designer, nor do I have access to the original designer or any documentation, I'm just the person doing the maintenance. From what I can understand from the code the original data source WAS a table in an XSD Data Set, but then shifted from that to an identical in in-memory dataset assigned to the report using the code behind.

Comment: I understand your pain. ;) Unfortunately I don't have any practical experience with this particular situation. What I might try to do is create a new dataset that is identical to what you are currently trying to use, but give it a new name. Then maybe the designer would see the new dataset and have to completely reprocess it, and in turn, pulling in the new column. This may not be the optimal solution, though, and it may not even be possible in your particular situation. If that's the case, I apologize for not being able to be more helpful.